# copying columns from a text file

Tags: c

i have a text file which looks like this :

```
Flooding refers to all water that overflows a node, whether it ponds or not.
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                             Total   Maximum
                                 Maximum   Time of Max       Flood    Ponded
                        Hours       Rate    Occurrence      Volume     Depth
  Node                 Flooded       CMS   days hr:min    10^6 ltr    Meters
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1064                  0.15     0.000      0  00 00       0.000      0.35
   1065                  0.25     0.078      0  00 09       0.049      0.41
   1130                  0.25     0.626      0  00 00       0.106      0.90
   1155                  0.24     0.098      0  00 07       0.073      0.61
   1173                  0.25     0.106      0  00 15       0.022      0.76
```

i want to copy the numerical columns (no text) such that the resulting file is like as such :

```
   1064                  0.15     0.000      0  00 00       0.000      0.35
   1065                  0.25     0.078      0  00 09       0.049      0.41
   1130                  0.25     0.626      0  00 00       0.106      0.90
   1155                  0.24     0.098      0  00 07       0.073      0.61
   1173                  0.25     0.106      0  00 15       0.022      0.76
```

Till now i have managed to do this code in C :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
FILE *fs,*ft;
int ch;
int c;
fs=fopen("node.txt","r");
if (fs=NULL)
{
    puts("cannot open source file");
    exit(0);
}
ft=fopen("new_node.txt","w");
do
{
   ch=fgetc(fs);
   if (ch=EOF)
   break;
   else
   {
    if (ch>0)
    fputc(ch,ft);
   }
     ch++;
}
  while(1);
  fclose(fs);
  fclose(ft);
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that nothing is coming out of it. Can anyone help in this regard and provide a working code.

Comment: I would use other tools than C to perform this task, like awk (or perl, or python)

Comment: actually i have no knowledge of perl or python . Thats why iwas trying for C. Is it possible it DOS program?

Comment: added some solution below, in both languages. If you don't know them, learn them! It's worth the time. Furthermore, imho python is easy to pick up

Answer (score 1):

`if (fs=NULL)` assigns `NULL` to `fs` rather than comparing them.  Use `==` to test for equality instead i.e. `if (fs==NULL)`

The same applies to `if (ch=EOF)` later in your code.

Note that compiling with warnings enabled would probably have pointed out this assignment in a conditional expression.

These changes will let you copy the entire contents of your source file.  Look into `isspace` and `isdigit` if you only want to copy the lines which start with spaces/numbers.  unwind's suggestion of using `fgets` would make this much simpler.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Is anything printed out?  Can you step through the code using a debugger or add printf statements to see what code gets executed?

Comment: the code doesn't print anything . just i get a blank "new_node.txt" file.

Comment: You had the same problem in a second location.  I've updated my answer to list this too.  Btw, you'd have found this yourself if you'd tried enabling warnings as I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is obviously line-oriented; it makes *no* sense to read/write this data one character at a time.

Read a full line into a suitably-sized buffer (1024 bytes, maybe) using `fgets()`. Inspect the line, do determine if it's one you want to keep. If so, write ut out using `fputs()`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your problem is pretty easy: you just do not use the right tools. Indeed, in bash (installed by default on most Linux distributions and Mac OS X. For windows, install [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) or [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/)), just this does the job:

```
tail -n +8 copying_columns.data
```

This, in fact, starts printing the file at the 8th line, effectively skipping your header.
Awk offers a more generic solution:

```
awk 'x >= 2 {print}; /---/ {++x}' copying_columns.data
```

that is, print the line if we encountered two or more lines containing `---`. In perl, this can give:

```
perl -ne 'if ($x >= 2) {print $_;} if (/---/){++$x;}
```

or, if we put the perl script into it's own file, `copying_columns.perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $x = 0;
while (<>){
    if ($x >= 2){
        print $_;
    } 
    if (/---/){
        ++$x;
    }
}
```

Run with

```
 perl copying_columns.perl copying_columns.data
```

As a bonus, here is a Python version:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
for f in [open(fname, 'rb') for fname in sys.argv[1:]] or [sys.stdin]:
    x = 0
    for line in f:
        if x >= 2:
            print(line.rstrip('\r\n'))
        if line.find('---') >= 0:
            x += 1
    f.close()
```

Run with

```
python copying_columns.py copying_columns.data
```

This version comes with the extra advantage of resetting the counter between input files.

Finally, here are my two cents: learn (at least :) )  one of those tools: they are marvelously efficient, especially for [data manipulation](http://www.drbunsen.org/explorations-in-unix.html).